# Anchor a portion of a SwiftUI view during animation in an NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-animation

In the following code, I have a simple button that toggles the appearance of a rectangle between two elements in a `VStack`.

When this toggle happens, the enclosing `NSWindow` changes size immediately and then the contents changes with the animation.

A side effect is that the "Hello, World" `Text` appears to move in and out of place (where I would hope that the `Text` would stay anchored to the top).

Is there a way that I can do the following (with animation) where the `Text` element stays anchored at the top of the `View` and *doesn't move* while the rectangle comes into place and the `Button` slides down/up to accommodate the rectangle?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show window") {
            let window = NSWindow()
            
            window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable]
            
            window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: WindowContent())
            
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            
            window.center()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct WindowContent: View {
    @State private var showRectangle = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world")
            
            if showRectangle {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                    showRectangle.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }
        
            .fixedSize()
            .padding(20)
    }
}
```

[image]